# Small Claims Repayment

Tags: small-claims-court

I bought a used car from a private seller who claimed the car was in great working condition. I later found out the car has no working airbags, which the seller failed to disclose. The airbags had deployed, were ripped out, and the car was patched back up as if nothing happened. I sued the seller for this and won my case, so he is due to pay me so I can fix this issue with my car.
 Here is my issue. 1) The defendant has left the country and does not plan on moving back. 2) I do not have his contact information as he has changed everything, so I am only in contact with his mother, not him directly.

How can I get my money for my case I have won, when he is out of the country and does not plan on returning?

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't. You have a judgement, but must collect it for yourself. If you can find any of his property still in the country, you might be able to get an order to seize that property and sell it to pay the judgement.